# Excluding Parent Directory if Any File is New

Tags: powershell

My company has individual folders on a share for each project they are working on, and if no files inside one of those folders or its subfolders has been touched in the last six months, I want to move them to an archive location. If any one file within the folder or any of its subfolders have been modified in the last six months, I want to skip the entire parent directory. I'm most of the way there now, but my current iteration only skips the individual files, and I'm not sure how to specify skipping the entire parent. Here is my current script:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)
$Source = 'C:\Scripts\Source'
$Dest = 'C:\Scripts\Test Target'

Get-ChildItem $Source -File -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date} | ForEach {

    $actualSource = Split-Path $_.FullName
    $actualDest = Split-Path $_.FullName.Replace($source,$dest)

    robocopy $actualSource $actualDest $_.Name /SEC

}
```

When using my test directories, I have a folder C:\Scripts\Source\Drivers. The script copies that Drivers folder like I want it to, but if I put a newer file anywhere within that Drivers folder, I want the entire folder to be skipped. Currently, the folder and anything older than six months within the folder are still being copied, and it is just skipping the individual files which are newer.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Why aren't you using some form of archiving solution instead of solutioning this yourself in powershell?

Comment: Is there any software you'd recommend that could do everything I need it to? I don't have too much experience with software archiving solutions, especially ones that need granular control such as what I'm trying to accomplish with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pull back your copy and recurse statement one level up. First you want to iterate through all the parent folders. Then for each parent folder, recurse and check to see if there is any modified files, if there is, then copy the folder:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)
$Source = 'C:\Scripts\Source'
$Dest = 'C:\Scripts\Test Target'

$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory
Foreach($Folder in $ParentFolders){
  $NewFiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder -File -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date}
  if($NewFiles.Count -eq 0)
  {
    #Archive
    robocopy $Folder $Dest /SEC
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this gets me close, but it grabs folders one level lower than I'd like. I'd actually like to move the Parent Directories and everything in them. If I try changing the $Folder variable in the if statement to $ParentFolders, it doesn't seem to want to work either. So far, one of three things is happening, depending on little tweaks such as changing to $ParentFolders:
1. The script runs with no errors but does nothing
2. The script runs and copies some files in subdirectories, but not the correct parent directories
3. Robocopy gives weird errors about the files not existing(they do)